# Why is it not possible to select the click or open checkboxes when adding a Cloudwatch destination to an Amazon SES configuration set?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-ses

I am following the Amazon docs to add a Cloudwatch destination to a configuration set in our Amazon SES account. It is possible to select the Bounce, Delivery and Complaint checkboxes in this modal, but the other checkboxes are disabled. Why is this? Must I take care of some setup in my Cloudwatch dashboard first?

[image]

If I try to set up an SNS destination instead of a Cloudwatch destination, I can indeed select the Click and Open checkboxes.

[image]